# sum value using foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am making an e-commerce website. Where I have to show the total amount of all the product which is in the cart. But when I try to get the total amount of all product so it only shows the price of the last product Here is the code

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = 0; 
if($result > 0){   
    foreach($result as $row){ 
        $price = $row['price'];
        $total += intval($price);
    }
```

Because the price was in varchar in the database so I converted into an int using intval() method 
and echo $total

```
 <td class="pro-subtotal"><span><?php echo $total; ?></span></td>
```

But its showing amount of the last row in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need this code. First of all you do not need `if($result > 0)`. Your variable `$result` is an array, not a number, so you can't compare it to a number. `intval` makes very little sense if you use the result in an arithmetic context. Assinging a variable into another variable without doing anything useful with it is pointless so remove `$price = $row['price'];` too.

What you are then left with is a simple loop with arithmetic addition.

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = 0; 
foreach($result as $row){
    $total += $row['price'];
}
```

This is not the smartest idea, since such operations should be done in SQL not in PHP. Is there any reason why you have to do it in PHP? If not then simply aggregate the values in SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS total FROM salesOrders WHERE saleId = ?
```

Then in PDO fetch a single column only.

```
$total = $query->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if($result > 0){ ... }
```

should be

```
if(count($result) > 0){ ... }
```

Comment: But it's still not calculating the sum of all price

Comment: @Azeez can you pleas4 post the updated code? and also the query please

Comment: Take into account that `intval` returns 0 in case of error. Maybe `'price'` doesn't exist in the array?

Comment: @Mochilo for the moment there could be 1000 reasons why it's not working, and until he posts the query, we couldn't know